# Asymptotic notation proof

Tags: asymptotics, computational-mathematics

I am trying to proof below but stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

---

Give an example of functions such that $f(n) > 0$ and $g(n) > 0$ for all natural $n$, and $f(n) \in O(g(n))$,

but $\lg(f(n)) \notin O(\lg(g(n)))$.

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) (i.e. LaTeX commands) for mathematical notations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $f(n) = 2$ and $g(n) = 2 ^ {\frac{1}{n}}$. Then

$$\frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \to 2$$

$$\frac{\lg{f(n)}}{\lg{g(n)}} = n \to \infty$$

(Assuming $\lg = \log_2$)

Comment: Thanks @idok for all you help. Sorry to bother you but if you can elaborate it a bit. I am unable to understand how n -> ∞ (n tends to infinity) will proof lg(f(n)) /∈ O(lg(g(n)))

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: @SaurabhGupta I proved that $\frac{\lg{f(n)}}{\lg{g(n)}} \to \infty$. so in particular, $\frac{\lg{f(n)}}{\lg{g(n)}}$ is unbounded, which means $\lg{f(n)} \notin O(\lg{g(n)})$

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it. It was really helpful and I appreciate it a lot.